# What is prototype.js doing with the invoke statement here?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I am refactoring some `prototype.js` to `jquery` and I came across some code that I don't fully understand.

```
var form = this.up('form');
form.select('select').invoke('setValue', '');
form.submit();
```

What is the `invoke('setValue', '')` doing?  Here is the code that I am using to replace the `jQuery`

```
var $this = jQuery(this);
var $form = $this.closest('form');
$form.find('select').val('');
$form.submit();
```

but I am not positive that the `.val` is doing the same thing?  I was wondering if someone could give me some direction?

Comment: Lets have a look at the documentation: http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/, http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/Element/prototype/setValue/

Answer (score 1):

Invoke applies the same method (with the same arguments) to multiple elements in an array or other Enumerable container.